# pagination prop for antd table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, antd

I am using Table component from antd library. I want to pass pagination prop to the Table component. In the docs it says pass the pagination config object which refers to the Pagination component itself.

So I am passing the pagination object using Pagination component prop names as keys like 
`<Table pagination={{pageSizeOptions : ['30', '40'], showPageSizeOptions : true}} {...otherProps} />`

But when I inspect the Table component in react-inspector I don't see the pagination prop in component props but it is there in the component state and has default values.

How to use the pagination prop for Table component?

Comment: I am using antd 3.2.1

Comment: I found this article very useful https://blog.emiketic.com/2018/implementing-pagination-using-react-redux/

Answer (score 10):

Replace "showPageSizeOptions"  to "showSizeChanger".

i.e.

```
<Table pagination= { {pageSizeOptions: ['30', '40'], showSizeChanger: true}} rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
```

Answer (score 2):

creating a pagination config object and using it with object spread syntax worked!

`config = { 
    pagination : {
        pageSizeOptions : ['30', '40'], 
        showSizeChanger : true 
    }
}`

`<Table {...config} {...otherProps} />`

It worked but don't understand the why and what is the difference between the two semantics of the two syntax.