# How To use pagination in antd table?

Tags: antd

> I'm on Antd vs.3.1.4. I am using Table component from antd library. I
>   want to pass pagination prop to the Table component.
>   But when i am go next page and return to previous page row will
>   increase automatically
>   i want only 3 row will be show and others are goint to pagination

```
<Table

     columns={columns}
     pagination={{ pageSizeOptions: ["5", "10", "15", "15"], defaultPageSize: 3 }}
/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pagination prop for antd table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206995/pagination-prop-for-antd-table)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set `pageSize` as well. Additionally `pageSizeOptions` only work when `showSizeChanger` is `true`.

```
pagination={{ pageSizeOptions: ["5", "10", "15", "15"], pageSize:3, showSizeChanger:true, defaultPageSize: 3 }}
```

The size changer dropdown is only visible if screen is wide enough, so if its not visible you might need to adjust the viewport.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-maxwell-gpne1?file=/index.js